# TypeError: 'ec2.instancesCollectionManager' object is not iterable when mocking with Moto?

Tags: python, pytest, moto

The following code got error of "TypeError: 'ec2.instancesCollectionManager' object is not iterable" when casting to `list(instances)` using Moto.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def aws_credentials():
    os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN'] = 'testing'
    os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'] = 'testing'
    os.environ["MOTO_ALLOW_NONEXISTENT_REGION"] = 'True'
    os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-east-1'

@pytest.fixture
def session(aws_credentials):
    return boto3.session.Session()

@mock_ec2
def test_get_nodes(session):
    #session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='us-east-1')
    filters = None
    Node.get_nodes(session, filters)
    instances = session.resource('ec2').instances
    print(list(instances))  # ERR
    assert any(instances)  # ERR
```

The instance in `Node` class can be casted to `list()` if not using Moto.

```
class Node(NodeBase):
    @classmethod
    def get_nodes(cls, session, filters):
        instances = session.resource('ec2').instances.filter(Filters=filters)
        return instances
```

`print(type(instances))` got `<class 'boto3.resources.collection.ec2.instancesCollection'>` whenever using Moto or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In node, you are calling `instances.filter()`, which returns a `<class 'boto3.resources.collection.ec2.instancesCollection'>`. This collection is iterable and hence can be unpacked into. a list.

However, in your test, you are not calling `filter` on the .instance. Here, the type of `instances` is
`<class 'boto3.resources.collection.ec2.instancesCollectionManager'>` which is not iterable. If you call .all() of .filer() on that, you get back a collection again which is iterable.